# What would I need to do to be able to apply `sort` to this type?

Tags: haskell

I have this complicated type

> ```
> newtype CalendarDay = MkCal (Either AvailableDay UnAvailableDay)
>                            deriving (Show,Ord,Eq)
> ```

Which is made up of

> ```
> newtype AvailableDay = MkAD (Text, C.Day)
>                       deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
> ```

and

> ```
> newtype UnAvailableDay = MkUAD (Either ScheduledDay (C.Day, Out_Of_Office))
>                           deriving (Show,Ord,Eq)
> ```

ScheduledDay looks like this

> ```
> data ScheduledDay = MkSDay C.Day Product ScheduledState
>                    deriving (Show,Ord,Eq)
> ```

I will have a [CalendarDay], that I want to sort by the Day that is buried in all those other types. What will I have to do to make that happen?

Comment: Those types look like they could use some refactoring. You should probably move the `Day` field out to the `CalendarDay` type, and deal with the availability separately.

Comment: like this? newtype CalendarDay = MkCal (Day,Availability)?

Comment: I would use a plain data type instead of a newtype over a tuple, i.e. `data CalendarDay = MkCal Day Availability`. Similarly, unless you have a good reason to, I would also replace the uses of `Either` with a data type with multiple constructors, e.g. `data Availability = Available Text | Unavailable ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function `day :: CalendarDay -> Day` which extracts the day from your type. You can do this with your current types, but as I mentioned in my comments, I would recommend refactoring those first. It should then be a simple matter of doing some pattern matching to extract the `Day` field from your type.

Once you have this function, use `sortBy` from `Data.List` to sort using a custom comparison function. You can build one with `comparing` from `Data.Ord`, like so:

```
sortBy (comparing day) foo
```

where `foo :: [CalendarDay]` is your list of calendar days.

Comment: Thanks hammar. I thought about keeping things as they are for now, but you are right. I need to refactor first.

Comment: Since re-factoring, my code has gotten much cleaner, and a previously difficult task is now easily solved.